More keys in tablet mode
I have just installed Ubuntu 24.04 on convertible laptop.
How do I add more keys like esc, and Print Screen on virtual keyboard?
Attached is image...


You'll need to  use an extension like Improved OSK and customize it with an extension manager
You can install from the webpage or if you get the Extension Manager Flatpak or install with sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager you can search for and configure it from there
